# Thread-safe int wrapper in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, console, .net-core

My system is a .NET Core 7 console app, which starts some background threads. I need to pass some `int` values (counters, etc.) between the main and background threads, in a thread-safe manner.

Although I can pass an `int` by reference (e.g. `DoFoo(ref myInt)`), I can't assign it in the background thread (e.g. I can't pass it into the background thread class' constructor and save it as a field). So I decided to wrap it in a reference type, which I can pass that way.

The following class works, but I'd like to know if it is truly thread-safe (have I missed something?) and whether it can be improved.

```cs
public sealed class ConcurrentInt
{
  private int _value;
  public ConcurrentInt(int value) => _value = value;

  // update value atomically
  public void Add(int value) => Interlocked.Add(ref _value, value);

  // read freshest value
  private int Get() => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _value, 0, 0);

  // allow `ci = ci + 1` and `ci += 1` and `ci += 1234`
  public static ConcurrentInt operator + (ConcurrentInt concurrentInt, int x)
  {
    _ = concurrentInt ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(concurrentInt));
    concurrentInt.Add(x);
    return concurrentInt;
  }

  // allow `int x = ci` instead of `int x = ci.Get()`
  public static implicit operator int(ConcurrentInt concurrentInt) {
    _ = concurrentInt ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(concurrentInt));
    return concurrentInt.Get();
  }

  // ci.ToString("N0")
  public string ToString(string? format = null) => Get().ToString(format);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the implicit operator?

Comment: @PeterCsala Nicer syntax in the caller, e.g. `var x = ci;` instead of `var x = ci.Get();`.

Comment: Then why do you expose the Get as well?

Comment: @PeterCsala Thanks. I guess I used both forms in the calling code - I suppose you are right, it is neater to expose just one of them. But with Add, I use this type as a readonly field in the caller, so it's convenient to use Add.

Comment: Do you plan to use this type as a counter (always just increment) ?

Comment: @PeterCsala No, I use it for other things too, e.g. keeping track of various values, so the caller uses `ci += 1` but also `ci += 1234`.

Comment: It is still an increment :) My question was more about decrement, multiply or subtract.

Comment: @PeterCsala Ha :-)... No, I only need increment (addition), for now. For subtraction I could pass a negative into `Interlocked.Add`. I doubt I'll ever need multiplication or division. This is not to perform arithmetic, just to "keep track of things" - how many times something happened, was used, total counters, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments section I think the code can be greatly simplified:

```
public sealed class Counters
{
    private int intCounter = 0;
    public int IntCounter
    {
        get => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref intCounter, 0, 0);
        set => Interlocked.Exchange(ref intCounter, value); 
    }
}
```

This allows you to hide the usage of `Interlocked` while exposing the data as `int`.

Here is a simple usage example:

```
var c = new Counters();
var t = new List<Task>()
{
    Task.Run(async () => { c.IntCounter += 100; await Task.Yield(); c.IntCounter++; }),
    Task.Run(async () => { ++c.IntCounter; await Task.Yield(); c.IntCounter = c.IntCounter + 20; })
};

await Task.WhenAll(t);
Console.WriteLine(c.IntCounter);
```

The main drawback of this design is that it allows `c.IntCounter = -1` as well.

Comment: You've converted the tricky bits into a property, which is an interesting alternative. Thanks!

Comment: Easy fix with:  `set => Interlocked.Exchange(ref intCounter, value < 0 ? 0 : value);`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   // read freshest value
>   private int Get() => Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _value, 0, 0);
> ```

Using an `Interlocked.CompareExchange` for a read is relatively heavy, you could use an `Interlocked.Add` with 0 and return the result. Your own `Add` could return the new value as well for that matter, that can make it more useful, almost for free.

Consider also whether you really need the read to be interlocked, as opposed to it being merely atomic. But the consequences are subtle.

> ```
> _ = concurrentInt ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(concurrentInt));
> ```

If the result was used it would be a common pattern, but with throwing away the result this is unusual. You could use `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull`. Calling a method that throws instead of a "bare" throw also makes it more likely that uses of `operator +` can be inlined.

Comment: "...common pattern, but with throwing away..." that is the syntax currently used in much of MS' documents. Your take on this matter as well as the inlining trick is interesting, thanks.